# How can I restore my SMS messages from google drive or samsung cloud backup?

Tags: backup, sms, restore

My previous phone is damaged. I have created backups to Google Drive and Samsung Cloud. I see that Messages are backed up to both cloud services, but I cannot access the content of these backups. How can I access to my previous SMS messages without a factory reset on my new phone?
My new phone is not a Samsung and I do not necessary want to restore the messages to my new phone. I just want to read the content of backups.

Comment: I don't think Google allows Google account users direct exposure to app backups. Even takeout.google.com does not list these backups.